# In Finnegans Wake, what could "enos chalked halltraps" refer to?

Tags: james-joyce, finnegans-wake

In *Finnegans Wake*, what could the phrase ["enos chalked halltraps"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uF47v_9olEs) refer to? Some, possibly flawed, attempt at pest control?

> [30.1] Now  (to forebare for ever solittle of Iris Trees and Lili
> O'Rangans),  concerning the genesis of Harold or Humphrey Chimpden's
> occupational agnomen  (we are back in the presurnames prodromarith
> period, of  course just when enos chalked halltraps) and discarding
> once for all those theories from older  sources which would link him
> back with such pivotal ancestors as the Glues, the Gravys, the
> Northeasts, the Ankers and the Earwickers  of Sidlesham  in the
> Hundred of Manhood or proclaim him offsprout of vikings who had
> founded  wapentake and seddled hem in Herrick or Eric,  the best
> authenticated version, the Dumlat,  read the Reading of
> Hofed-ben-Edar,  has it that it was this way.

The question pertains to before 1939.

I don't think there is a need to analyze the whole passage, the question is focused on

> (we are back in the presurnames prodromarith period, of  course just
> when enos chalked halltraps)

I am aware of the standard readings, but am not satisfied. None explain all three words simultaneously. It is my experience with *Finnegans Wake* that there is usually a clear simple Duh! behind the complex text, and that straying into the esoteric often misses the point.

This is what is known at [Finnegans Web & Wiki](http://www.finnegansweb.com/wiki/index.php/Chalked_halltraps):

> #### Chalked halltraps
>
> - **enos chalked halltraps:** ECH → HCE (backwards)
> - **chalked:** (*slang*) slashed, scratched → Enos the magician chalking circles in the ground to conjure spirits
> - **chalked:** drew with chalk → chalk drawings in palaeolithic caves are some of the earliest examples of art → Kevin (=Shaun) "chalked oghres on walls" at [FW 027.05-06](http://www.finnegansweb.com/wiki/index.php/Page_27)
> - **choked** ?
> - **talked:** in the time of the Biblical Enos men first invoked the name of God (Genesis 4:26)
> - **hall trappings:** pictures on the wall in the hallway → Vico's First Age, when primitive men made their homes in caves (and chalked images on the walls?)
> - **hallow-traps:** an old meaning of *hallows* is the gods of the heathens → Enos's chalk circles trap the spirits of false gods
> - **hilltops**
> - **Hell-traps:** to trap and compel demons from Hell
> - **Hallstatt:** a Celtic Iron Age culture
> - **traps:** anticipates the traps HCE uses to capture earwigs

Perhaps someone attempting but failing to control ants or roaches (chalk trap) is suggested by earlier context?

While Chapter I.2 is by far the easiest in the novel, I can find no satisfactory interpretation of the phrase "enos chalked halltraps".

- I would accept any answer that can give all three words suitable context simultaneously.

---

Note that "trap" is Dutch/Afrikaans for "stair", so we may be looking at hall stairs, although of course "trappe" is "stairs", but for Joyce "traps" could easily mean "stairs".

Comment: Those are some mighty unusual words through that whole passage.

Comment: It's night time so some of the words are difficult to sense :)

Comment: I found [some ideas here](http://www.finnegansweb.com/wiki/index.php/Chalked_halltraps), but I won't venture to even try an answer because I can't make head of tail of this.

Comment: I know those sources, but I am just wondering about the phrase "chalk halltrap". Ignore the rest. I will update OP

Comment: @fundagain I don’t think you *can* ignore the rest. If ‘enos’ is the biblical grandson of Adam and Eve, who lived to be 905, it may be intended to refer to tally marks. If prodromarith refers to a pre-numerical time, chalking up tally marks to count centuries of life works.

Comment: Actually since this whole section seems to be about the acquisition of names, perhaps enos chalking halltraps is somehow related to recording the family genealogy (all those ‘begats’). I can’t find a satisfactory explanation of the word ‘halltrap’ itself however. (Given the phonetic colloquialisms and unique idiolect of FG though, that’s hardly a surprise.)

Comment: I cannot get all three words to make sense simultaneously. I was thinking drawing chalk lines to trap ants, based on the semi-myth that ants don't cross chalk lines, and I have a few texts about using chalk lines to force ants into a sink, say. But for Halltraps I am now also thinking hall stairs (from the Dutch/Afrikaans trap for stair)

Comment: Eno's "Fruit Salt" - known everywhere as simply Eno's - is a popular antacid (ANT acid) which was first sold in 1852. "Be prepared for emergencies by always keeping a bottle in the house". Its main ingredients are sodium bicarbonate and citric acid, though most antacids use calcium carbonate: chalk.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian That's a wonderful find. It ought to be mentioned at Finnegansweb.com.

Comment: @Old Brixtonian You may be onto something there. A trap is also a mouth

Comment: @Jos Really? I don't know the place but unless there are rewards - fags or cake say - please feel free to mention it there.

Comment: @fundagain Ah yes. I remember 'Shut yer trap!' as a popular school playground injunction.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I saw that reference on google books and can clearly see that there’s a journey from whisky to liver salts in that occurrence I’d enos. I’m struggling more with the link to a period before names and numbers?

Comment: @Spagirl Despite the "archetypal" words, here we are looking at the life span of one man, HCE, who will eventually marry Anna (who was married to Finnegan, but he fell from a ladder and died). "Presurnames" is a period of Irish history, and could just mean "early", but could refer to a time before Anna started collecting multiple surnames: nee, then Finnegan's, and after his death HCE's.  "prodromarith" could mean before marriage.

Comment: @Spagirl I can't see one yet. This question has me dusting off my Finnegans Wake and thinking I might get through it this time, aided by Finnegansweb and this place.

Comment: There is a new reading in progress up to Chapter I.7 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HgCjtd2iPU

Comment: @Spagirl The time before numbers, is back when Finnegan was still alive "Bygmester Finnegan, of the Stuttering Hand, freemen’s mau-rer, lived in the broadest way immarginable in his rushlit toofar-
back for messuages **before joshuan judges had given us numbers**
or Helviticus committed deuteronomy" Finnegan drank too much.